# Rare characters on log file using log4j2

Tags: log4j2

When logging to a file with a sync logger, rare characters occasionally appear. See below "^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c" (this does not happen with 1.2.17).

2015-04-02 13:58:51 Starting messaging service ...

^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c2015-04-02 13:59:06 Messaging service successfully started.

2015-04-02 13:59:06 Starting balancer test port ...

My log4j.xml is this: http://www.grupoventus.com/download/log4j.xml

Thanks,

Joan.

Answer (score 1):

These strange characters are Linux/UNIX consoles codes (see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)). These codes are often used to specify the color to use in the console, but here it seems to specify the terminal type, I found this [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/drivers/char/console.c):

```
/*
 * this is what the terminal answers to a ESC-Z or csi0c query.
 */
#define VT100ID "\033[?1;2c"
```

Check which appender/logger is used to know who is trying to use such special characters in the "%m" part of the log entry (Log4j log message).

Comment: Hi, the issue is that using exactly the same aplication and just switching from log4j2.2 to log4j1.2.17, these characters dissapear. I don't print this kind of chars in any place in my app. I only send plain text to the log.

Comment: Are you sure the Log4j configuration file you showed here is the one Log4j is using? By the way, this configuration file should not be usable by Log4j v1, so the issue may not necessary comes only from the Log4j version, but also from its configuration, since it can't be the same. Also: if some log entries start with these characters but not others, it should tell you something, like which appender/logger is faulty?

Comment: The previous log4j configuration file is for log4j2. The one I'm using for log4j1.2.17 is this: http://www.grupoventus.com/download/log4j_1.2.17.xml. And yes, the logger that is causing problems is the LOGGER_SYSTEM (appender SYSTEM_LOG). The other logs work fine, but no idea where this characters come from.

Comment: Hello, any idea about this? Thanks.